# SNS Subscription Filter Policy to send emails for SNS with give subject or message body

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, subscription

SNS notifications are triggered in multiple workflows in a process which needs to be received by different emails (audience). For instance, a SNS notification is triggered using the below python code:

```
def send_sns_notification(self, **kwargs):
        try:
            response = self.snsClient.publish(
                TargetArn=kwargs.get("arn"),
                Message=message,
                Subject=kwargs.get("subject"),
                MessageStructure='string'
            )
        except ClientError as e:
            logging.error(e)
            return False
        return True
```

I need to define subscription filter policy so that a particular email address will only receive emails if the subject is "Test Subject 1"

I have tried adding the below policy with filter scope selected as `Message body`. It didn't work.

```
{
  "subject": [
    "Test Subject 1"
  ]
}
```

What is the correct way of filtering based on SNS subject or is there any way to filter raw string SNS notifications based on Message Body content?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to add the subject as part of the message being sent. I dont think that you can filtyer based on subject, only Attributes and body.
So either add the subject as a MessageAttribute string or in the Message body sent

on attribute could be something like:

```
{
  "MessageAttributes": {
    "subject": {'DataType': 'String', 'DataValue': '<your_subject_here>'}
  }
}
```

FYI: not entirely sure about 'DataValue' key, just verify that
And then make sure to hjave the policy set to message attributes (it would be the same as the one you have already)

Hope it works